# tone sandhi represented in Pinyin

Tags: pinyin, sandhi

According to Wiedenhof's *A Grammar of Mandarin*, page 25,

> When following a frst or a second tone, and simultaneously preceding a
>   non-neutral tone, a second tone is pronounced with a high level pitch
>   55 (high to high), i.e. as a frst tone. **This diference can be represented in  Pinyin**: ānmián yào ~ ānmiān yào ‘sleeping pills’.

Does "represent" here mean that, instead of the citation/lexical tones, the new tones after tone sandhi can be used as well?

Comment: With all due respect to the author, I do found a lot of description in the mentioned book quite inaccurate and sometimes quite misleading. For example `ānmiān yào` is never a valid pronunciation in any authoritative mandarin text book that I ever read. `ānmián yào` is the only pronunciation. So called `tone sandhi` do exist in everyday Mandarin but this specific case is highly likely to be just some very localized accent that's been misinterpreted by the author.

Answer (score 4):

No, [this is not standard Pinyin](https://www.iso.org/standard/13682.html), if this form of tone sandhi is written out. The author is simply trying to convey what it *would* look like if written out (instead of retranscribing it with Chao-style tone letters).

This type of sandhi ("Mandarin T2 Sandhi", for *Tone 2 Sandhi*), is mentioned only rarely, because it is a ["prosodic-driven process"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=HztsDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA6), i.e. it happens because the syllable is not in a strong position in the overall 'rhythm and melody' ( = prosody) of the utterance.

However, T2 sandhi is not an ingrained feature of standard Mandarin or even any one dialect of Mandarin (unlike T3 sandhi), but a "[variation](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YWWYBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA16)", and one that is far from universal.